# Compiling alsa-utils 1.1.0 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, alsa

I have compiled and installed alsa-lib 1.1.0 and moved on to compiling and installing the new alsa-util. The ./configure works:

```
./configure --disable-bat --disable-xmlto --disable-alsaconf --with-curses=ncursesw
```

however the make fails and I have had no luck finding a resolution:

```
Making all in topology
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/apps/alsa_utils/alsa-utils-1.1.0/topology'
gcc  -g -O2   -o alsatplg topology.o -lasound -lasound -lm -ldl -lpthread
topology.o: In function `main':
/home/pi/apps/alsa_utils/alsa-utils-1.1.0/topology/topology.c:99: undefined reference to `snd_tplg_new'
/home/pi/apps/alsa_utils/alsa-utils-1.1.0/topology/topology.c:105: undefined reference to `snd_tplg_verbose'
/home/pi/apps/alsa_utils/alsa-utils-1.1.0/topology/topology.c:107: undefined reference to `snd_tplg_build_file'
/home/pi/apps/alsa_utils/alsa-utils-1.1.0/topology/topology.c:114: undefined reference to `snd_tplg_free'
/home/pi/apps/alsa_utils/alsa-utils-1.1.0/topology/topology.c:110: undefined reference to `snd_tplg_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:318: recipe for target 'alsatplg' failed
make[1]: *** [alsatplg] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/apps/alsa_utils/alsa-utils-1.1.0/topology'
Makefile:352: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

I understand that this error means that undefined references exist but I cannot understand why?

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds as if the compiler does not pick up the newly installed alsa-lib headers. Does `/usr/include/alsa/topology.h` exist? Was the new alsa-lib installed there?

Comment: Hi CL, yes the /usr/inclde/alsa/topology.h does exist and the definitions of the references are indeed there.

Comment: Oops, that is actually a linker error. So check where libasound.so is installed.

Comment: @CL., libasound.so seams to be in /usr/lib: 

`-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 3731824 Feb  4 23:27 libasound.so.2.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      18 Feb  4 23:27 libasound.so.2 -> libasound.so.2.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      18 Feb  4 23:27 libasound.so -> libasound.so.2.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     938 Feb  4 23:27 libasound.la
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Feb  4 23:27 pkgconfig
pi@teststream:/usr/lib $ pwd
/usr/lib
`